# OOP design of little helper classes

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

Lets say I have a class C that is doing some job.

For that I need a little very simple helper class H (e.g. representation of a pair or a 3-tuple). H is only needed in C.

I would put H inside of C.

```
class C
{
   void foo ()
   {
     // ... use H to do the job more easy ...
   }

   class H
   {
      // very simple and contained stuff
   }
}
```

Is putting H inside of C a good idea? I do it to have it contained and at the place I think it should be and nowhere else. But I am not sure it is good design.

Comment: if the scope is really only C, I would make the helper private method(s)

Comment: Define the class like so: `private static final class H`, which reads like: *I only use this class here, I don't intend to use inheritance with it and it doesn't access `C`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More of an addendum:

First: if H objects are supposed to exist without an owning C instance, then H should be `static`. You might even want to make it private.

Then, keep in mind: you have an inner class here, so H's full name is actually something like *whatever.package.com.C.H*. In other words: you really tied H to C.

What if you decide at some point that H has enough other aspects that make it worth to be "its own" thing? Then you might have to touch some more code, to turn your *whatever.package.com.C.H* into *whatever.package.com.H*.

Thus you *could* consider to make H a toplevel class, but to *not* make it public. So you keep it in C.java, but not as inner class!

( but of course, that really depends on "style", I think that the Google java coding standard tells you to only have **one** top level class per .java file)

Final words: if there is a way to turn your H class into something that *could* be used in other places, then I would go forward and right away make it a public class of its own. If re-using seems reasonable, write your code so it can be easily re-used! And a 3-value tuple doesn't sound like it is very specific to anything, so it sounds like a candidate for re-use.

Answer (score 6):

That is a very good design. The visibility of the classes, variables or methods should always be limited to the only required scope, never more.
If later this class needs to be used outside the inner class, just move it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is good design. What you're trying to do is called **inner class**.you can also make it private. If it doesn't need exclusive access to the members of the outer class, make it a static nested class , it will require less memory.